# How to model the Rest API URL

Tags: java, spring, rest

There is a model that represents a Book.

```
class Book {
    String author;
    String isbn;
    String releaseDate;
}
```

I would like to create an API that returns a list of `isbn` for books whose release date is the provided one by the user. What how this URL should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What how this URL should look like?

The URL can look any way you like, provided that it is consistent with the production rules defined in [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#appendix-A).

You'll probably want a *range* of resource identifiers, where the resources vary by release date alone.  That suggests that you want to use an identifier pattern that you can describe using a [URI template](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570).

If users interact with your resources using a web browser, then you'll likely want URI that work the way that HTML forms expect, with application/x-www-form-urlencoded key value pairs as the query part.

For long lived resources, you'll want URI that doesn't need to change - see this [guidance from TBL in 1998](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI)

But beyond simple mechanical rules like these, the machines don't care what spelling conventions you use -- so you should choose spellings that make the life easier for some humans you care about (ie: choosing a spelling that meets the needs of OPS reviewing an HTTP access log, or choosing a spelling that is easy to document, or choosing a spelling that is easy to recognize in a browser history....)

---

For the release date part, you'll probably want the date fields to match one of the ISO 8601 formats; for example, see the documentation for [java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

If the HTML use case is important, then make sure you review [date inputs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#date-state-(type=date)).

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using `spring` & `rest` so here what I am thinking :

```
@RestController(value="/getBooks")
public class Controller{
..
@GetMapping(value="/getIsbn")
public List<String> getIsbn(@RequestParam String releaseDate){
 ..
}
}
```

And your URL would look like(considering you are parsing `YYYY-MM-DD` date format) with `GET`:

```
   https://<your context root>/getBooks/getIsbn&releaseDate=2022-05-03
```